# Array of arrays of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do you declare an array of arrays of arrays? Say I have an array `s[]`. `s[0]` will contain an other array `a[]` and `a[0]` will contain an array `b[]`. How would you do it with pointers?

Comment: http://cdecl.org

Comment: Do you want `s[0]` to be an array or to be a pointer to the elements of an array? Do you want `a[0]` to be an array or to be a pointer to the elements of an array?

Comment: To clarify Eric's questions: one is a matter of 'clever' indexing and is actually just one big array.  The other uses actual pointer references, and the final multi-dimensional array is no longer contiguous.

Comment: Are you coming from PHP? :-)

Comment: Well in the end they both achieve the same, the only thing is that with pointer references I the length of my strings won't be fixed. For what I want to do, either one of them work, but the pointer version is obviously less of a hassle. @Kerrek: Nope, C was my first :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// b is an array of int.  (N is some number.)
int b[N];

// a Option 0:  a is an array of M arrays of N int.  (M is some number.)
int a[M][N];

// a Option 1:  a is an array of M pointers to int.
int *a[M];
a[0] = b;
// Other elements of a must also be assigned in some way.

// s Option 0:  s is an array of L arrays of M arrays of N int.  (L is some number.)
int s[L][M][N];

// s Option 1:  s is an array of L arrays of M pointers to int.
int *s[L][M];
s[0][0] = b;
// Other elements of s must also be assigned in some way.

// s Option 2:  s is an array of L pointers to arrays of N int.
int (*s[L])[N];
s[0] = a; // Can use a from a Option 0, not a from a Option 1.
// Other elements of s must also be assigned in some way.

// s Option 3:  s is an array of L pointers to pointers to int.
int **s[L];
s[0] = a; // Can use a from a Option 1, not a from a Option 0.
// Other elements of s must also be assigned in some way.
```

There are also options in which each object is a pointer at its highest level, instead of an array. I have not shown those. They would require defining something for the pointer to point to.

Comment: +1:  Nice answer especially for answering questions the OP should have asked but didn't know enough to do so.

Comment: Don't you want to do `s[0] = a` in option 2? (to make it 3-dimensional)

Comment: @anatolyg: Yes, I think that is better.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach.

```
int length = 10;

int b[5] = {0,1,2,5,4};

int c[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int** s = malloc(sizeof(int*) * length);

s[1] = b;
s[2] = c;
```

and so on...

This example is for 2 layer. Making pointer `s` to be  `***s` and appropriate changes, to make it 3 layer.

Comment: `s+1` and `s+2` are not lvalues and cannot be on the left side of assignments. You may have intended `s[1]` and `s[2]`. And this gives `s` only two layers, not the three requested in the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ya you are correct. `s+1` is not compiling. But I thought `s+1` to be a syntatic sugar of `s[1]`. Ref :  For instance, in the C language the a[i] notation is syntactic sugar for *(a + i)  - Wikipedia.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: `s+1` is not `*(s+1)`. The asterisk makes a world of difference.